# invalid stdimage image path in admin

Tags: python, django

I am a bit new in django, and i was using stdimage module in my model. When i upload an image through admin and save it, on opening the model object i find the field having three things

1. Current image: which gives the link to the already uploaded image eg uploaded_images/2012/11/28/map_7.jpeg
2. Change: which is provision to change the image
3. Delete: with checkbox for deleting the uploaded image.
   When i add an image and save the object, i get the error IOError at /admin/oxer/site/41/ and when i click the image link i get 404 error, with the image url appearing as itech.com/admin/oxer/site/49/uploaded_images/2012/11/04/image_1.jpeg  instead of itech.com/static/uploaded_images/2012/11/04/image_1.jpeg (notice i've removed 'admin/oxer/site/49' and replaced with 'static').

I guess the ioerror is brought by the wrong url. how can i make it have the right url?

Here is my model:

```
class Site(CommonMixin, ImageMixin):

    __metaclass__ = TransMeta

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Description"))
    has_airport = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    do_not_miss = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Do not miss"))
    recommended_stay = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Recommended stay"))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Address"))
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_("State"))
    price = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Price"))
    good_to_know = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Good to know"))
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.ManyToManyField('Region', blank=True, null=True)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField('Interest', blank=True, null=True)
    map = StdImageField(
        upload_to='uploaded_images/%Y/%m/%d',
        max_length=255,
        height_field='height',
        width_field='width',
        size=(453, 294, True),
        thumbnail_size=(195, 150, True),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    location_lat = models.DecimalField(
        u'Location (latitude)', max_digits=10, decimal_places=7, default=0,
        help_text=u"You can use http://www.getlatlon.com to get a location's coordinates"
    )
    location_lon = models.DecimalField(
        u'Location (longitude)', max_digits=10, decimal_places=7, default=0,
        help_text=u"You can use http://www.getlatlon.com to get a location's coordinates"
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of an ImageField is like this

```
upload_to='uploaded_images/%Y/%m/%d',
```

This path is relative to your MEDIA_URL.
Let's suppose you're visiting `http://site/admin/auth/user`.
If in this page you have a link of this type

```
<a href="uploaded_images/2012/11/28/file.ext">Anchor</a>
```

The link will point to

```
http://site/admin/auth/user/uploaded_images/2012/11/28/file.ext
```

Which is what you get, and is obviously wrong.

Long story short, the answer is that you MUST prepend the path stored with `MEDIA_URL`
Which may be

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' (the slash at the beginning points to the domain root)
```

or

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://domain/media/' (might be redundant)
```

Comment: after adding MEDIA_URL = '/media/', the image path now becomes itech.com/media/uploaded_images/2012/11/28/map_7.jpeg since stdimage is using the value of MEDIA_URL. It brings 404 error when clicked because My STATIC_URL='/static/'. The problem is, the path should be itech.com/static/uploaded_images/2012/11/28/map_7.jpeg for it to show the image. I can't use the same value for STATIC and MEDIA_URLs. Any help?

Comment: I fixed it by STATIC_URL='/static/' and MEDIA_URL='/static\t/'. I don't know whether the '\t' will have any effect in the project.                                                              Thanks Steve. As you suggested, MEDIA_URL='...' is what was needed so that its val would be put  itech.com/"HERE"/uploaded_images/2012/1/28/map_7.jpeg. Its now working. when i click the link, the image is displayed.